# Select2 in multiple mode in MVC generates first value only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 plugin.
I know that in multiple mode the selected values should come as a comma seperated string, but instead I only get the first value.

**Html:**

```
<form action="~/Home/SendData">
    <select multiple id="selectElement" name="Data">
        <option value="Val1">Val1</option>
        <option value="Val2">Val2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectElement").select2();
});
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult SendData(string data)
 {
     //data contains only val1.
     return View();
 }
```

**Fiddler:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

in your case, model binder cannot create string array of values, please, fix your action like this:

```
public ActionResult SendData(string[] data)
{     
   return View();
}
```